# Global substitution shell script not working

Tags: shell, ubuntu, sed

I have a shell script like:

```
for fl in /home/dr/*.txt; do
mv $fl $fl.old
sed 's#$1#$2#g' $fl.old > $fl
rm -f $fl.old
done
```

and I run it like `./script.sh find replace`, yet nothing happens and there is no output. Why is this?

Comment: Inside single quotes `'` both `$1` and `$2` are probably not what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're using single quotes instead of double quotes. With single quotes, `sed` interprets the string literally (i.e. it will search for the string `$1`, not the first argument).

Below is a functioning version of what you were trying to do. Note that I've replaced temporary file usage with sed's "in-place" editing.

```
for fl in /home/dr/*.txt
do
  sed -i "s#$1#$2#g" $fl
done
```

However, **you can one-line everything**!

```
sed -i "s#$1#$2#g" /home/dr/*.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for your nice answer. If $1 contains a '/' will this cause problems? This is why I went with the # symbol instead. And is the '.' omitted from the txt intentionally?

Comment: Yes it would cause a problem, and `#` is a much better choice for just that reason. Sorry for that. I just use slashes as a force of habit.

Comment: And no, the omitted `.` was left out as a result of my sloppiness. Good catch, and my apologies again.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions +1, but for some reason, the one-liner isn't editing any files. I haven't tested the multi line one

Comment: The reason it's not working is because everything inside single quotes is taken literally (i.e. it will search for the string `$1`, not the second argument). My answer's fixed now. It should do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i "s#$1#$2#g" /home/dr*.txt
```

The problem you had is single quotes around sed commands does not allow interpolation.

Comment: It looks like you accepted the wrong answer. The answer that *was* accepted is broken.

Comment: That's better, @David. One more thing: the backticks are not needed.  If you remove those I'll upvote your answer as well.  Reason: they distract from the original problem.

Comment: @Henk, I just tested that... it appears you're right! Thanks for the correction, that changes a lot of my bash scripts. Editing my answer now.

Comment: @Henk, it's been changed. Would you mind pointing out future mistakes as a response to the answer? If I hadn't checked this thread again, I never would have had the chance to be corrected.

Comment: Can you align the `do` with the `done`?  Alternatively, remove `do` and put a ` ;do` on the previous line.  Both are good style.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14988/discussion-between-henk-langeveld-and-david)